# How do you delay a z-index transition?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that transitions in and out by opacity, however the z-index on it hides the transition out. See the jfiddle for clarification.

http://jsfiddle.net/sprigmendle/16zfv3jx/2/

Whats the most simple way to put a timer, or transition on the z-index so it only happens after the fade out? A jfiddle of the solution would be appreciated. I also don't want to use Jquery if possible.

---

html

```
<a href="#pop">appear</a>
<div id="big"></div>

<div id="pop" id="pop_close">
    <a href="#pop_close">disappear</a>
</div>
```

---

css

```
#big {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    background: blue;
}

#pop{
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    background: yellow;
    opacity:0;
    position: relative;
    left -7em;
    top: -5em;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}

#pop:target {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#pop_close:target {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: try setting transition for all http://jsfiddle.net/16zfv3jx/4/

Comment: This looks interesting: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gboJf

Comment: Very interesting way of manipulating a single div with two ids!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate a delay by adding `z-index` to your transition. Since there's no animation on `z-index`, it will take 2 seconds to see the effect.

```
#pop {
    transition: opacity 2s, z-index 2s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
}
```

The `cubic-bezier` timing function will stop the jumping effect that [sodawillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782133/how-do-you-put-a-timer-on-a-z-index/27782179#comment43974511_27782179)  was speaking about.

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9es1p5gb/)</kbd>

Comment: or `all 2s`! (in this case you have 2 properties changed, so `all` should be good)

Comment: `all` can sometimes be problematic (changing size etc) when it doesn't need to be animated.

Comment: I think sometimes the opacity jumps to the final value, you could also do `transition: opacity 2s, z-index 0s 2s;` meaning 0s transition but 2s delay.

Comment: @sodawillow That will most likely break the fade-in, since it will wait 2 seconds before going on top.

Comment: I don't understand your input then : "Since there's no fading on z-index, it will wait 2 seconds to trigger." --- Nevermind, I think I do now :)

Comment: you can animate/transition z-index, as it is countable.
so, yes, there is a "fading" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Make z-index transition with 2s delay to the transition and remove it when transitioning in.

In #pop

```
transition: opacity 2s, z-index 0s 2s;
```

In #pop:target

```
transition: opacity 2s, z-index 0s 0s;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzxcg98d/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to not transition to/from `z-index: auto` as that won't work.

Comment: This was actually the crucial information! `z-index` css property **must** be set on both the original class **and** the "highlight" class in order for the `transition-delay` of `z-index` to work properly.